# Django: create custom order in model

Tags: python, django

In my website, I can create multiple albums with pictures. How can I get control over the order in which the albums or pictures appear on the page? Ordering by date or name is pretty straightforward, but what is the best way to have absolute and user friendly control over the order. It should be easily possible to set any album first, second, third, ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the special `order` integer field and sort by it:

```
class Album(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    order = models.IntegerField(default=1000)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('order', 'name')
```